# How to disable pageName after mapping page route?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I'm using ASP.NET Core with *Pages* and I've created a controller like this:

```
namespace Demo.Pages.Channel
{
    public class IndexModel : PageModel
    {
        public string ChannelUrl { get; set; }

        public void OnGet(string url)
        {
            ChannelUrl = url;
        }
    }
}
```

And I've tried to map the route:

```
services.AddMvc()
    .AddRazorPagesOptions(options =>
    {
        options.Conventions.AddPageRoute("/channel/index", "/{url}");
        options.Conventions.AddPageRoute("/home/error", "/channel/index");
    });
```

And these are some cases I've tested:

[image: 1]

[image: 2]

It works fine. But it still *worked* when I tried:

[image: 3]

In the options above, I've mapped the url `/channel/index` to the error page `/home/error` but the page cannot be redirected. Why?

I want to map the url like: `localhost:44392/{url}`, but `localhost:44392/channel/index`

How can I do that?

Comment: Which version are you using ? If i use .net Core 2.1 and use your configuration ,when /home/error doesn't exist , it will reproduce your issue , if exists , then it worked . Please firstly check whether you have error page in Home folder inside pages folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've got the solution that made me hard to understand why we need to use this configuration:

```
.AddRazorPagesOptions(options =>
{
    options.Conventions.AddPageRoute("/channel/index", "/{url}");
    //options.Conventions.AddPageRoute("/home/error", "/channel/index");
});
```

To map the route, we config like this in the razor page(s):

```
<!-- index.cshtml -->
@page "/{url}"

<!-- profile.cshtml -->
@page "/users/{userId}/profile"

<!-- error.cshtml -->
@page "/custom/error"
```

So, we need to delete the configuration `.AddRazorPagesOptions()`.